# uiautomatorviewer is not working, throwing error that SWT folder does not exist

Tags: android, uiautomatorviewer

Uiautomatorviwer is not working , it is giving the below given error

SWT folder '..\lib\location of your java installation.' does not exist.
Please set ANDROID_SWT to point to the folder containing swt.jar for your platform.

I have tried everything that was mentioned on stackoverflow, but nothing seem to work.

Please be kind and help me!!!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can anyone please help

Comment: Just to clarify further, I am trying to work with Android studio.  When try to run UIAUTOMATORVIEWER . It crashes with the above error. Please let me know if more information is required.

Answer (score 2):

It is working now. 
I did set ANDROID_SWT to point to the folder containing swt.jar for my platform. and walla its working now.

Thanks for looking
Joe

Comment: This does not work for me, any other things you have changes to get it working?