# Uiautomatorviewer SWT exception

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, swt, uiautomatorviewer

Since StackExchange advised me to not ask for help or clarification on a [previously existing post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48128648/uiautomatorviewer-is-not-working-throwing-error-that-swt-folder-does-not-exist#), I am making a new thread.

On Windows 10x64 I downloaded the [Eclipse SWT](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.7.2-201711300510/) (in second-to-last section of Downloads page), set my `ANDROID_SWT` environment variable to `<download location>\swt.jar`, and have attempted to run `uiautomatorviewer` from `cmd` again, only to receive the same error message as when I tried to use the SWT bundled with eclipse:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Listener
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Listener
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

Has anyone else encountered this error, and if so, what was the root cause?

Thanks in advance for your time and help!

Comment: Since you got an exception and not a compile error, what is happening is that Eclipse is aware of the library for building, but your deployment environment does not know where to find the SWT jar.  Please [edit] your question and explain how you are deploying and running your project.

Comment: Hi, @JimGarrison! I am attempting to run `uiautomatorviewer` from cmd, and therefore I believe I only need to set the `ANDROID_SWT` path variable. However, despite my having set this variable, as well as having added Java to my `PATH` variable, I am receiving the above exception.

Comment: You need to add the `swt.jar` file to the classpath.  Try that.

Comment: Hmmm, I made a new variable `CLASSPATH` since it did not already exist in my Environment Variables, and added the absolute path of `swt.jar` downloaded from Eclipse, and yet I receive the same exception... I'm going to reboot my computer in case the changes to envionrment variables only takes effect when you logout and create a new session!

Comment: Here are some of the environment variables I've set so far:

1) ANDROID_HOME - location of .\Android\sdk (within the Android Studio directory)
2) ANDROID_SWT - location of swt.jar
3) CLASSPATH - location of swt.jar
4) PATH - appended bin directory for JDK 8 (I read that JDK 9 is incompatible with uiautomatorviewer), as well as  %ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools and the standalone adb tools directory... I am still experiencing the same exception. Thank you again for your continued help with this issue!

Comment: @JimGarrison I have solved the issue, as per my follow-up comment :) Thanks for commenting!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Precisely follow [these instructions](http://www.automationtestinghub.com/setup-android-environment-variables/). I made the mistake of trying to download the Eclipse SWT in order to troubleshoot other issues I was having; setting this different SWT version in the `CLASSPATH` and `ANDROID_SWT` environment variables caused this exception.

Answer (score 2):

In my case adding ANDROID_SWT to environment variables or editing PATH didn't solve the problem. Therefore I found a different solution via help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48254790/solving-noclassdeffounderror-exception-with-swt) question.

Running **uiautomatorviewer.bat** and output :

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Control
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:650)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:632)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Listener
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
```

**Solution :**

Go to : https://www.findjar.com/ and search for missing class.
In this case search for class :

```
org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control
```

For your case it is:

```
org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Listener
```

Names of the classes in the error can change, but all the classes needed comes from **.jar** file that will be downloaded.

In the results click :

```
[CLASS] org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control
```

or for your case :

```
[CLASS] org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Listener
```

Download latest and suitable file for your OS. [This](https://www.findjar.com/jar/org/eclipse/platform/org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64/3.106.3/org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64-3.106.3.jar.html) was the latest and suitable for Windowsx86_64 currently.

Put downloaded **.jar** file into :

> C:\Users\{userId}\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\lib

or equivalent path for your OS.

Now **uiautomatorviewer.bat** should run without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

**In my case the exception was**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
  org/eclipse/swt/custom/TableTreeItem
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.initializeHandler(OpenStrategy.java:270)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.<init>(OpenStrategy.java:108)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.hookControl(StructuredViewer.java:1213)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ColumnViewer.hookControl(ColumnViewer.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.hookControl(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1452)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.hookControl(TreeViewer.java:274)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.<init>(TreeViewer.java:137)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.<init>(TreeViewer.java:124)
at com.android.uiautomator.UiAutomatorView.<init>(UiAutomatorView.java:361)
at com.android.uiautomator.UiAutomatorViewer.createContents(UiAutomatorViewer.java:66)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:431)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:790)
at com.android.uiautomator.UiAutomatorViewer.main(UiAutomatorViewer.java:78)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.custom.TableTreeItem
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
... 13 more
```

Steps followed for the solution

1. Go to https://jar-download.com/
2. Search for the missing jar file in my case it was **org.eclipse.swt.custom.tabletreeitem**
3. Download the jar file compatible with your system Mac/Win/Linux (In my case it was mac
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JP2e4.jpg)
4. Extract the jar file and copy it
5. Go to the lib folder inside SDK (Android/Sdk/Tools/Lib
6. Paste the jar file into the lib folder
7. Restart your terminal or cmd
8. Run the command again for cd $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
9. Run the command ./uiautomatorviewer

**Alternatively**

Try to download the swt jar file with a different version and copy it to the respective folders.
Follow this thread :

https://github.com/android/android-test/issues/911#issuecomment-849389068

Answer (score 0):

Make sure JDK location selected in Android studio is same as JDK set in environment variable.

[image]